# Xamarin ClassFileTransformer Was Not Found

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to upgrade my XF to the latest version (5.0.0.2612) but with no luck.

I got the error as below

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Warning in obj\Debug\130\androidx\jl\5db50f87-a270-4886-b397-fecb21d6ff35.jar:kotlinx/coroutines/debug/AgentPremain$DebugProbesTransformer.class:
Type `java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain$DebugProbesTransformer`
Warning in obj\Debug\130\androidx\jl\5db50f87-a270-4886-b397-fecb21d6ff35.jar:kotlinx/coroutines/debug/AgentPremain.class:
Type `sun.misc.SignalHandler` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain$$InternalSyntheticLambda$2$7895cd395e43c061a299e224a1d3672f97bd4610fe97f0e188c9c199a1620b54$0`
Warning in obj\Debug\130\androidx\jl\5db50f87-a270-4886-b397-fecb21d6ff35.jar:kotlinx/coroutines/internal/ClassValueCtorCache$cache$1.class:
Type `java.lang.ClassValue` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ClassValueCtorCache$cache$1`
Warning in obj\Debug\130\lp\147\jl\classes.jar:androidx/appcompat/widget/DropDownListView$GateKeeperDrawable.class:
Type `androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperCompat` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView$GateKeeperDrawable`
Warning in obj\Debug\130\lp\93\jl\classes.jar:androidx/room/paging/LimitOffsetDataSource.class:
Type `androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `androidx.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource`
Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 73992 > 65536). Try supplying a main-dex list
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position
 null
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:98)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:4)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: null
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.75.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:75)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.b(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:17)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:85)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 73992 > 65536)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.JT.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.n30.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:524)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.i30.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:371)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.F2.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:455)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:756)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:24)
    ... 5 more
Directory 'obj\Debug\130\lp\147' is from 'androidx.appcompat.appcompat.aar'.
Directory 'obj\Debug\130\lp\93' is from 'androidx.room.room-runtime.aar'.   AppName.Droid           
Error       Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 73992 > 65536). Try supplying a main-dex list AppName.Droid   C:\Users\root\Downloads\trial3-ori\trial3\AppName.Droid\D8
```

I have no idea what should I do. I have been actively looking on the SO but not found any solution. Please help.